# Why here is an error in ionic serve for new project?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a new ionic project with Angular

but while adding any import to `home.page.ts` get errors.

```
home.page.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public p: Platform) {}

}
```

if I remove  `import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';` it works fine.
here is the error message:

```
[ng]../../node_modules/ionicangular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/spinner/spinner.js:1:0-115 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/spinner'
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/spinner/spinner.js:100:0-42 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/spinner'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/split-pane/split-pane.js:1:0-130 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/split-pane'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs/tab-button.js:1:0-107 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs/tab-button.js:9:0-42 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs/tab-highlight.js:1:0-54 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs/tab.js:1:0-218 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs/tabs.js:1:0-163 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs/tabs.js:2:0-39 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Subject' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs/tabs.js:3:0-37 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs/tabs.js:157:0-42 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/tabs'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/thumbnail/thumbnail.js:1:0-42 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/thumbnail'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toast/toast-component.js:1:0-64 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toast'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toast/toast-component.js:12:0-42 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toast'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toast/toast-controller.js:1:0-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toast'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toggle/toggle.js:1:0-122 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toggle'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toggle/toggle.js:2:0-51 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/forms' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toggle'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar/navbar.js:1:0-81 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar/navbar.js:49:0-42 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar/toolbar-footer.js:1:0-74 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar/toolbar-header.js:1:0-74 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar/toolbar-item.js:1:0-111 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar/toolbar-title.js:1:0-138 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar/toolbar-title.js:44:0-42 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar/toolbar.js:1:0-89 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar/toolbar.js:94:0-42 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/toolbar'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/typography/typography.js:1:0-64 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/typography'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/virtual-scroll/virtual-footer.js:1:0-55 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/virtual-scroll'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/virtual-scroll/virtual-header.js:1:0-55 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/virtual-scroll'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/virtual-scroll/virtual-item.js:1:0-73 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/virtual-scroll'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/virtual-scroll/virtual-scroll.js:1:0-129 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/components/virtual-scroll'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/config/config.js:1:0-47 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/config'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/gestures/gesture-config.js:1:0-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/gestures'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/gestures/gesture-config.js:2:0-64 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/gestures'
    [ng] 
    [ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/gestures/gesture-controller.js:1:0-63 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/gestures'
../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/module.js:4:0-150 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/module.js:5:0-138 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/module.js:6:0-76 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/module.js:7:0-66 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/forms' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/navigation/nav-controller-base.js:1:0-72 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/navigation'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/navigation/url-serializer.js:1:0-47 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/navigation'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/navigation/view-controller.js:1:0-53 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/navigation'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/platform/dom-controller.js:6:0-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/platform'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/platform/keyboard.js:1:0-65 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/platform'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/platform/platform-registry.js:1:0-47 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/platform'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/platform/platform.js:1:0-45 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/platform'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/tap-click/haptic.js:1:0-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/tap-click'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/tap-click/tap-click.js:1:0-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/tap-click'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/transitions/transition-controller.js:1:0-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/transitions'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/util/base-input.js:1:0-60 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/util'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/util/form.js:1:0-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/util'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/util/ionic-error-handler.js:1:0-45 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/util'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/util/module-loader.js:1:0-69 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/util'
[ng] 
[ng] ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/util/ng-module-loader.js:1:0-53 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/Users/macbookshop/node_modules/ionic-angular/__ivy_ngcc__/es2015/util'
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/action-sheet/action-sheet-component.d.ts:1:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/action-sheet/action-sheet-component.d.ts:21:146 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Renderer'.
[ng] 
[ng] 21     constructor(_viewCtrl: ViewController, config: Config, _elementRef: ElementRef, gestureCtrl: GestureController, params: NavParams, renderer: Renderer);
[ng]                                                                                                                                                     ~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/alert/alert-component.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/app-root.d.ts:1:106 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ComponentFactoryResolver, ElementRef, InjectionToken, OnInit, Renderer, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/card/card-header.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/card/card-title.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/card/card.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 

[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/toolbar/navbar.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/toolbar/toolbar-base.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/toolbar/toolbar-footer.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/toolbar/toolbar-header.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/toolbar/toolbar-item.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/toolbar/toolbar-title.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/toolbar/toolbar.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/typography/typography.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/virtual-scroll/virtual-footer.d.ts:1:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/virtual-scroll/virtual-header.d.ts:1:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/virtual-scroll/virtual-item.d.ts:1:47 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/virtual-scroll/virtual-scroll.d.ts:1:179 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { AfterContentInit, ChangeDetectorRef, DoCheck, ElementRef, IterableDiffer, IterableDiffers, NgZone, OnChanges, OnDestroy, Renderer, SimpleChanges, TrackByFunction } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                                                                                                                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/virtual-scroll/virtual-util.d.ts:1:64 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { EmbeddedViewRef, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/config/config.d.ts:1:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/gestures/gesture-config.d.ts:1:37 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { HammerGestureConfig } from '@angular/platform-browser';
[ng]                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/module.d.ts:4:37 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 4 import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/module.d.ts:5:78 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 5 import { HashLocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy, PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';
[ng]                                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/navigation/deep-linker.d.ts:1:60 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/navigation/deep-linker.d.ts:2:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 2 import { Location } from '@angular/common';
[ng]                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/navigation/nav-controller-base.d.ts:1:132 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, ElementRef, ErrorHandler, EventEmitter, NgZone, Renderer, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                                                                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/navigation/nav-controller.d.ts:1:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/navigation/nav-util.d.ts:1:41 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { Renderer, TypeDecorator } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/navigation/url-serializer.d.ts:1:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/navigation/view-controller.d.ts:1:66 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ComponentRef, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/platform/keyboard.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { EventEmitter, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/platform/platform-registry.d.ts:1:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/platform/platform.d.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { EventEmitter, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/util/base-input.d.ts:1:70 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { AfterContentInit, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/util/base-input.d.ts:2:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 2 import { ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/util/base-input.d.ts:3:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 3 import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
[ng]                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/util/ionic-error-handler.d.ts:1:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/util/module-loader.d.ts:1:99 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { ComponentFactoryResolver, InjectionToken, Injector, NgModuleFactory, NgZone, Type } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 
[ng] 
[ng] Error: ../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/util/ng-module-loader.d.ts:1:43 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
[ng] 
[ng] 1 import { Compiler, NgModuleFactory } from '@angular/core';
```

1. ionic CLI 6.20.4
2. node version: v16.14.2
3. npm version: 8.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import it like this:

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
```

also make sure you have `@ionic/angular` in you `package.json` or you need to install it.